# Looping through HTML to match a string then apply a class

Tags: javascript

Given a bunch of HTML like

```
<li>
   <a href="/home">Test</a>
</li>
<li>
   <a href="/business">Test 2</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="/online">Test 3</a>
</li>

//and so on
```

And given a string like '/online' - is there a quick way of doing two things:

1. Finding where that string matches within the HTML and where it matches, applying a class to the parent LI?

So you'd end up with

```
<li class="active">
   < a href="/online">Test 3</a>
</li>
```

I can do this via looping etc but it just feels like there's a better more succinct way of doing it.

Comment: Pure javascript? Or jquery allowed?

Comment: Sorry, should have said - pure JS

Comment: Use `querySelector` with an attribute selector that targets this particular `a` element’s `href` content, and then go up to the parent element from there …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be easy with query selectors.

```
document.querySelector("a[href='/online']").parentElement.classList.add('active')
```

If you need more flexibility, just pass the "/online" part as a variable with string interpolation or concatenation.